Access blocked when trying google external login
I'm currently learning how to implement google external login in asp.net core MVC, but it doesn't work with me. I get this message with every time I try it, Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid.

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

I'm using .net core 5
Here is the code of my ConfigureServices method
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddDbContext<App_DbContext>( optionsBuilder =>
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection"));
    });

  
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>( options =>
    {
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 4;
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
    } )
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<App_DbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(CAO =>
    {
        CAO.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn";

        CAO.Cookie.Name = "LoginCookie";
    });

    services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        IConfiguration googleSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
        options.ClientId = googleSection["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = googleSection["ClientSecret"];
    });

}

Those are the two action that are concerned with the google external authentication
public IActionResult GoogleLogin()
{
    AuthenticationProperties ap = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse")
    };
    return Challenge(ap,GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
{
    AuthenticateResult result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    if (result.Succeeded)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    return View(nameof(SignIn));
}

In the Login form there is an anchor tag that redirects to the GoogleLogin action.
What I want to know is:

What those two actions do? I saw them in a tutorial but the he didn't explain them.
What is wrong or missing in the code to make this functionality work?
How does this external login keeps the user authenticated to the application while navigating its views & actions, does it use cookie based authentication? and if so which block of code is responsible for that?


Firstly, we have an offical sample here which also using services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle so that I'm afraid you are trying to do the same thing. Then the sample I shared used the Asp.net core default identity which using current user account to sign into the application. Integrate Google auth allows the app to let users sign in with therir google account without sign up in the MVC app.

But when users sign in with google account, the app help create a corresponding account in database, whenever this google account sign in again, it equals to use account stored in database.

When I try the signIn with google I get Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch  is the problem in the actions or in the ConfigureServices?

redirect_uri_mismatch ->this normally requires to set redirect url in cloud service and your application. Just like you know, google auth is a kind of external auth service, our app should redirect to sign in page and after sign in successfully, the google auth should redirect from its sign in page back to our app page, so that we need to set redirect url in cloud service. And we might also need to set it in our application when we use the related SDK, but in the document, it doesnt mention the configuration in app, so that I'm afraid only cloud configuration is required.
